# how to parse timestamp with nanoseconds

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

We have a timestamp like `2021-05-03T14:25:30.195737792Z` in our data and the Big Query ```` (```CAST('2021-54-03T14:25:30.195737792Z' AS timestamp)```) ```` fails with the following error:

> Invalid timestamp: '2021-05-03T14:25:30.195737792Z'

How can I convert the timestamp with nanoseconds to e.g. microseconds in UTC format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
select ts_as_string, 
  timestamp(regexp_replace(ts_as_string, r'([^.]+)(.)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?', r'\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8')) ts_as_timestamp
from your_table
```

if applied to dummy data as in your example  - output is

[image]

The shorter version is

```
timestamp(regexp_replace(ts_as_string, r'([^.]+)(.)?(\d{0,6})(\d)*', r'\1\2\3'))
```